# I'm stuck installing Crashlytics for Android using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation, crashlytics

I registered for Crashlytics, got their invitation and set up my account. Then I installed Crashlytics as described for Eclipse and restarted. Now I'm staring at the page https://www.crashlytics.com/onboard/pending showing "Add Crashlytics to your project".

What am I supposed to do? I have an open project in Eclipse. How do I add Crashlytics to it now to get to step 2 "Launch your app".

Of course I can launch my app just like this, but where is the connection to Crashlytics. It seems Crashlytics is waiting for some response from the installed Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the problem seems to have been in the Eclipse Development Bundle for Android by Google. After changing to ordinary Eclipse + the separate Android SDK, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 9):

[image]To Add Crashlytics to your App... follow these steps :

- Install **Crashlytics** for Android by opening Eclipse and going to `"Help",` then `"Install New Software".`
- In the download URL, type in "http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse".
- Check the box next to Crashlytics software and press "Next". You'll be asked to restart Eclipse and the plugin will be installed!

  Once the Plugin is installed..all your application will be listed in it and then select the one in which you want to add.

Best Wishes !

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did - according to the instructions. What do you mean by "listed in it". What is "it"? The plugin is installed, but I cannot find anything related to it in Eclipse.

Comment: Of course my projects are in my workspace (package explorer). They were there before. Where is the plugin? I cannot find a view related to it. How can I add Crashlytics to a certain project (maybe not to all of them)? How do I get the reports? I have deliberately crashed an app, but nothing happened.

Comment: Firstly, you have to register yourself to `http://www.crashlytics.com/` .
Once you completed with the installation of crashlytics plugin just restart your eclipse you will find a small red icon at the top of your eclipse IDE.

Comment: Of course I did this first. But when installing the plugin into Eclipse, I saw nothing happen, so I did not get the chance to enter my credentials into the plugin (which I would expect to be necessary). This is where I'm stuck.

Comment: I just tried it and its working in my case .... which Eclipse IDE you are using ???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37199/discussion-between-ryderz-and-holger-jakobs)

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps** [here](http://download.crashlytics.com/android/eclipse/), if you're stuck on adding Crashlytics to Eclipse.

(you're supposed to add the codes to your app to hook up Crashlytics)

Summary: To add Crashlytics to your app, follow the instructions within their widget (plugin).

This should show items such as

- Add code to the Manifest.xml
- Add code to your initial/startup Activity  to initialize the Crashlytics system.

Comment: I cannot see "their widget (plugin)". The looks of my Eclipse hasn't changed.